# Shopware:Admin cannot override login module

Tags: shopware6

Shopware:Admin
I try to override the [login module](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-login/page/index/index.js):

```
// main.js
import './module/sw-login';
...
```

```
// module/sw-login/index.js
import template from './sw-login.html.twig';
const { Component } = Shopware;
Component.override('sw-login', {
    template
})
```

```
// module/sw-login/sw-login.html.twig
{% block sw_login %}
   test
{% endblock %}
```

The code above doesn't do [override the template](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-login/page/index/sw-login.html.twig), what is the error here?

Answer (score 2):

This component can't be overriden. Well in theory it could, just like any other component. However it will only be used when requesting the administration in an unauthenticated state. In that state no plugin javascript assets are being loaded, including overrides of that component. Otherwise it would expose installed plugins to anyone requesting the login page of the administration. That would be undesirable as newly detected security vulnerabilities in plugins could be exploited and it would then make it very easy for attackers to find shops using those plugins.

There is a workaround, by extending the base template of the administration and injecting the javascript asset of your plugin manually. But it's not exactly best practice.

```
{% sw_extends '@Administration/administration/index.html.twig' %}

{% block administration_favicons %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script nonce="{{ cspNonce }}" type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            Shopware.Application.injectJs('{{ asset('administration/js/swag-example-plugin.js', '@SwagExamplePlugin') }}');
        }, false);
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```